# Mongodb:how to group by list of objects

Tags: mongodb, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have a below student collection which has List optional and am aggregating the collection group by List.

```
   {
    "_id" : "57e3e55c638cb8b971",
    "firstName" : "St1_firstName",
    "lastName" : "St1_lastName",
    "email" : "St1_firstname.lastName@xxx.com",
    "subjects" : [
        {
            "_id" : "35a344d888dd8b363",
            "code" : "00 00 00",
            "name" : "subject1"
        },
        {
            "_id" : "23a344d888dd8b335",
            "code" : "01 00 00",
            "name" : "subject2"
        },
        {
            "_id" : "45a344d888dd8b987",
            "code" : "01 01 00",
            "name" : "subject3"
        }
    ],
    "category" : {
        "_id" : "76a344d888dd8b887",
        "label" : "label"
    },
    "classroom" : {
        "_id" : "5877df01937e1f97942c9e06"
    }
}
```

Below is the GORM snippet used to aggregate collection group by list

```
DBObject unwind =  new BasicDBObject('_id',new BasicDBObject('$unwind','$subjects'))
        unwind.append('subjects','$subjects.code')
        unwind.append('count', new BasicDBObject('$sum', 1))
        DBObject group = new BasicDBObject('$group', unwind)
        queryPipe << group
```

### This is not working ,Could you correct the code

Getting NullPointerException when I tried with below complete code

```
List queryPipe = []
        DBObject matchclassroom = new BasicDBObject('$match', new BasicDBObject('classroom', params.classroom))
        queryPipe << matchclassroom

        final DBObject unwind = new BasicDBObject('$unwind', '$students')
        final DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject('_id', '$students.code')
        groupFields.put("count", new BasicDBObject('$sum', 1))
        final DBObject group = new BasicDBObject('$group', groupFields)
        queryPipe << group

        List facetsList = []
        Student.collection.aggregate(queryPipe).each { fct ->

                def studentsList = fct.'_id'.student

        }
```

Comment: why are you assigning unwind pipeline object to $group pipeline object ,    can you show what error your'e getting.

Comment: try like this,                                                                                        DBObject unwind =  new BasicDBObject('_id',new BasicDBObject('$unwind','$subjects'));


DBObject group = new BasicDBObject(['$group': [
    '_id'           : '$subjects.code', 
    'count'      : ['$sum' : 1]
]]);

AggregationOutput aggregationOutput = collection.aggregate([unwind, group]);
aggregationOutput.results().each { dbObject ->
    // Do something with your results
}

Comment: Before the above code have implemented  List queryPipe = []
        DBObject matchroom = new BasicDBObject('$match', new BasicDBObject('classroom', params.planroom))
        queryPipe << matchroom

Comment: then   Studen.collection.aggregate(queryPipe).each { fct ->
            String subjectId = fct.'_id'.subjects
            Map subjectInfo
            if (subjectId ) {
                subjectInfo= Subject.get(subjectId)?.properties.subMap('id', 'label')
            } 
            facetsList << [id: subjectId, count: fct.count, subjects: subjectInfo]
        }
        return facetsList

Comment: do you have any updates?

Answer (score 0):

your doing some mistakes for structure of code.

```
DBObject unwind =  new BasicDBObject('_id',new BasicDBObject('$unwind','$subjects'))
```

Here, creating $unwind Object.

```
DBObject group = new BasicDBObject('$group', unwind)
```

Here, creating $group Object. But, you add $unwind Object for inside of $group Object.

Comment: I need to count no of occurrences,that is way used  unwind.append('count', new BasicDBObject('$sum', 1))

Comment: getting  invalid operator '$unwind error even i am using the above 2 lines of code